# Understanding iteratee-functions in Haskell

Tags: haskell, enumerator, loops

I'm trying to figure out what's iteratee I/O in Haskell. I checked the following Haskell-Wiki with some [definitions](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Enumerator_and_iteratee).

I don't understand the meaning of the second, third and the last two lines of that function:

```
enumerator :: FilePath -> Iteratee (Maybe Char) o -> IO o
enumerator file it = withFile file ReadMode
  $ \h -> fix (\rc it -> case it of
    Done o -> return o
    Next f -> do
      eof <- hIsEOF h
      case eof of
        False -> do
          c <- hGetChar h
          rc (f (Just c))
        True -> rc (f Nothing)
    ) it
```

I know, what the iteratee function does, but I don't understand some lines.
The other functions on this wikipage are really mysterious. I don't understand what they do, because I miss some explanations.

Answer (score 4):

The lines you mention aren't enumerator-/iteratee-specific, though I can try to explain them.

---

```
withFile name mode = bracket (openFile name mode) (closeFile)
```

In other words, `withFile` opens a file, passes the handle to the given callback, and ensures that the file is closed after the callback completes.

---

`fix` is a fixed-point combinator.  For example,

```
fix (1 :) == 1 : 1 : 1 : 1 : ...
```

It is generally used to write self-recursive functions.  TFAE:

```
factorial 0 = 1
factorial n = n * factorial (n-1)

factorial n = fix (\f n -> case n of 0 -> 1; n -> n * f (n-1)) n
```

---

We can rewrite the same function without these constructs:

```
enumerator :: FilePath -> Iteratee (Maybe Char) o -> IO o
enumerator file it = do
  h <- openFile file ReadMode
  let rc (Done o) = return o
      rc (Next f) = do
        eof <- hIsEof h
        case eof of
          False -> do
            c <- hGetChar h
            rc (f (Just c))
          True -> rc (f Nothing)
  o <- rc it
  closeFile h
  return o
```

although it's not entirely accurate as `withFile` handles exceptions and this doesn't.

Does that help?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it would help if the lambda function were named.

```
enumerator :: FilePath -> Iteratee (Maybe Char) o -> IO o
enumerator file it = withFile file ReadMode $ stepIteratee it
  where
    stepIteratee (Done o) _h = return o
    stepIteratee (Next f) h = do
      eof <- hIsEOF h
      case eof of
        False -> do
          c <- hGetChar h
          stepIteratee (f (Just c)) h
        True -> stepIteratee (f Nothing) h
```

`stepIteratee` will keep stepping through both the file and the iteratee until the iteratee comes to a halt.